# Using fuzzywuzzy

Tags: python, pandas, fuzzy-search, fuzzywuzzy

The dataset I have is manually filled addresses.

The city I wanna look for is 'İstanbul'. It has a Turkish character and I'm running into some encoding issues as well. For example, lower()'ing the İ in İstanbul won't return me a character I can pick up with a regular 'i' in a regex pattern.

Therefore, as well as other reasons, I changed my approach to fuzzy string searching. I want to give reference strings to my fuzzy lookup algorithm: '/ist' and 'İstanbul' — these are the reference values to be looked up for in my address column.

Example of rows with phrases I want to catch:

```
...İSYTANBUL...
...isanbul...
...Istanbul...
...İ/STANBUL...
...,STANBUL/ÜSKÜDAR...
isatanbul
iatanbul
İSTRANBUL
isytanbul
/isanbul
```

These are full addresses so I found partial_ratio to be better working compared to ratio.

My goal is to use fuzzywuzzy.partial_ratio at the row level with the string 'istanbul' or '/ist. And use the score partial_ratio returns to get a True or False for that row index's preferred column —referenced as `'istanbul mu'` in code.

The code I've developed is below but it stops at about 25k rows every time I make this run. And it's abysmally slow. Do you think there's a more efficient to accomplish the task?

```
def fuzzy(string, df, columnname):
        fullrange = len(df[columnname])
        for i in range(fullrange):
            if fuzz.partial_ratio(string, df[columnname][i]) > 70:
                df.loc[df.index == i, 'istanbul mu'] = True
            else:
                df.loc[df.index == i, 'istanbul mu'] = False
```

Comment: You can use [Unidecode](https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/) to "flatten" the accented characters to make for a simpler search space (and you can then use `lower()` as you like).

Answer (score 1):

This approach is doing a lot better. Using .process may wield better results but for reference:

```
def applyfuzzy(row):
    if fuzz.partial_ratio('the string', row['column holding the address to be queried']) > 65:
        return True
    else:
        return False
df['preferredcolumn'] = df.apply(applyfuzzy, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

As a faster alternative to your own answer you can replace FuzzyWuzzy with [RapidFuzz](https://github.com/maxbachmann/RapidFuzz), which has a faster implementation of `fuzz.partial_ratio`

```py
from rapidfuzz import fuzz
def applyfuzzy(row):
    return fuzz.partial_ratio('the string', row['address_column'], score_cutoff=70) > 70

df['column'] = df.apply(applyfuzzy, axis=1)
```